# redux-form field validation level does not accept functions in validate inline

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

following this example:

https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/

validator are:

```
const maxLength = max => value =>
  value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined
const maxLength15 = maxLength(15)
```

for field username:

```
 <Field
    name="username"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    validate={[required, maxLength15, minLength2]}
    warn={alphaNumeric}
  />
```

if I change in validate ,  maxLength15 for maxLength(15) does not work:

validate={[required, maxLength(15),, minLength2 ]}

why I need to create another function "maxLength15" to validation works, because  "maxLength(15)" does not throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically you need to create the validation function outside of your `render()` method because every time the form gets rendered a new function would be created.

The docs state: `Note: if the validate prop changes the field will be re-registered.`

So you can see in a console that inline functions cause the field to `UNREGISTER_FIELD` and then `REGISTER_FIELD` again.